# @Autowired Spring annotation with struts2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2

I'm newbie of Spring, I try to understand how `@Autowired` annotation works with a struts2 action. This is my scenario:

**UserBean.java**

```
public class UserBean {
     private String userName;
     private int userAge;
     private String userGender;
     private String userJob;
     private String[] userHobbies;

     /*Getters and Setters */
}
```

**UserAction.java**

```
@Component
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserBean> {

     @Autowired
     private UserBean userBean;

     public String execute() {
         return SUCCESS;
     }

     public String addUser() {
         return SUCCESS;
     }

     public UserBean getModel() {
         return userBean;
     }

     public UserBean getUserBean() {
         return userBean;
     }

     public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
         this.userBean = userBean;
     }
 }
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gmail.amato.giorgio.*" />

<bean id="userAction" class="com.gmail.amato.giorgio.UserAction"></bean>
<bean id="userBean" class="com.gmail.amato.giorgio.UserBean"></bean>
```

Now my program is fine, and I don't have any error: I can see a form, fill that and see a result back to me.

My question is: If I using `@Autowired` annotation, why I have to write bean id for the userBean? It should be  injecting automatically by the Spring Container?

What is the advantage using `@Autowired` annotation if I have still to write both bean definition in my `applicationContext.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `UserBean` appears to be a data carrier and shouldn't be a spring managed bean unless you have only one User object in your application.

Secondly, the `content:component-scan` would take care of only classes that are annotated with `@Component`. Since you didn't annotate UserBean class, it won't be automatically identified and `@Autowired` unless you declare it explicitly as a bean, just like the way you did in your context file.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, so basically in this situation I should mark as `@Autowired` annotation the bean (just in this case, also it isn't a dao or a service), delete just the bean id of the action from the `applicationContext.xml`. Is it right?

Comment: In this case is there no way about removing everything (I mean all the bean definition) from my `applicationContext.xml`?

Comment: As long as you have the beans annotated with `@Component` and are present in the packages that are configured to be scanned, in `context:component-scan` base-package list, no bean definition is needed in the context.xml file.